# Can we build a project in flutter with different ui packages for different platforms

Tags: flutter, material-ui, fluent-ui

I want to build a flutter project, in that

- for windows using fluent ui
- for macos using macos ui and
- for mobile apps using material ui.

Inner content will be the same for all platform just the layout and features makes difference.

so can i do that, and if yes then whats the approch...

I have tried to build some demo projects, but as soon as I integrate another platforms ui or their  features, the project gets crash.

I expect the flow in that I can make platform according ui seprate for all platforms and the screens will be in common.

Comment: yes, you can....

Comment: thank you for your response. but what's the approach?

Answer (score 1):

This question may be answered with personal opinions but anyway , for create `multiplatform` app in flutter , your difficult task is handle UI on `multi-screen` size and `responsive` it .

you can using `responsive_builder` package and `flutter_screenutil` .
in some conditions need another way to use an package .
for using `responsive_builder`  on `web` and android device use this trick:

```
main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(builder: (context) {
      return kIsWeb
          ? const MainWidget()
          : const ScreenUtilsWidget(widget: MainWidget());
    });
  }
}

class ScreenUtilsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenUtilsWidget({Key? key, required this.widget}) : super(key: key);
  final Widget widget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(360, 690),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        splitScreenMode: true,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return widget;
        });
  }
}

class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    // blablabla
    );
  }
}
```

and for using in widgets do like below:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          ScreenTypeLayout(
            // you can define custom breakpoint for any widget .
            breakpoints: MainSizes.digitalProfileBreakpoints,
            desktop: Stack(//blablabla),
            tablet: Stack((//blablabla),
            mobile: Stack((//blablabla),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
```

You maybe need the `dart:html` handles in all app, but this file are limited on the web (or You need to do something different on the web than on an Android device!).

you can create 3 file and handles this mode.

file `web.dart` :

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

void reload() {
  html.window.location.reload();
}


String cookie = "";
```

file `native.dart` :

```
void reload() {}

String cookie = "";
```

file `switch_native_web.dart` :

```
import 'native.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'web.dart' as switch_value;

class SwitchNativeWeb {

  static String cookie = switch_value.cookie;

  static void reloadWeb() {
    switch_value.reload();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 

I know this part about responsive and layout builder, I just want to work on the same UI but with different platforms, like if I want to play with the title bars of macOS and windows desktop applications then how can I play with that and not interfere with any other part of my system to get crash or damage my code.

Thank you again for your efforts to understand and help me with my problem.

Comment: While implementing for multiple platforms, you will come across many small details. Your question is not a debug and answer type. It is better if you have a code that has an error and ask it in a separate question ,  it would be easy to explain in more details.

Comment: okay, I'll share my next question link on this. Thanks for reply

Comment: dear @axy if this answer helpful please set tick :)